# How do I set "skipLocalNotificationReady" for ionic-native plugin 'Local Notifications'

Tags: cordova-plugins, angular7, ionic-native, ionic4

I need to set `window.skipLocalNotificationReady = true` but in an ionic 4 project.

I want to stop the local notification events until the device is ready. Therefore I need to set `window.skipLocalNotificationReady = true`, according to the plugin.

But in **app.component.ts** this doesn't work.I get the error, that 'skipLocalNotificationReady' is not part of 'Window'.

Itried `cordovaPropertySet()` but it tells me, that the plugin is not installed (it is).

```
constructor(
    private localNotifications: LocalNotifications,
) {
    //window.skipLocalNotificationReady = true

    cordovaPropertySet(
        this.localNotifications,
        'skipLocalNotificationReady', 
        true);

    this.initializeApp();
}
```

Is there any workaround or a possibility that `cordovaPropertySet()` will work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]
Yes! I have the same problem. After 20 times to try. I see that I call it too late. So I move that line sooner, before call `app.component.ts`. It is in `main.ts`.

you can see the picture or view this:

```
// main.ts
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

(<any>window).skipLocalNotificationReady = true;

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

beside that. You must make sure that you have this function `.fireQueuedEvents()` because only `cordova-plugin-local-notification@0.9.0-beta.3` have that feature:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it isn't completely working. After updating to beta 3 I tried the things you said but nothing happened when the app was terminated.

Comment: It worked when i used `(<any>window).skipLocalNotificationReady = true;` and the ionic-native interface. And I needed to fire the Events in a hasPermisson() promise.

Comment: Just for completeness, I followed this answer (with upgrading to beta 3, running ionic cap sync), used the hasPermission() promise per @dmnkthfx - then finally, I wrapped all that in a platform.ready() promise, with both the event listener followed by the fireQueuedEvents() call inside. So it was platform.ready() => hasPermission() => { notifications.on('click).subscribe() followed by notifications.fireQueuedEvents() }